# Which tool to use for C/C++ documentation?

Tags: xml-documentation, code-documentation

Which tool is better for documentation of C,C++ and Java code out of 'Docbook' or 'doxygen' or any Can you please tell me any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use doxygen. For your need you can refer to the Wikipedia for comparison among the documentation generators.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators

Comment: Is there any thing like,We should run Doxygen from 
ubuntu only.? Can we run it from Windows also using DoxyWizard tool?

Comment: Yeah ! Executable is there for windows too. You can install that. Accept my answer if it was informative for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used NaturalDocs and found it to be great tool!